# Track mouse speed even when cursor is at edge of screen

Tags: javascript, mouse

I wrote a little Javascript app to track and display the x- and y- components of the mouse's velocity. It subtracts the cursor's previous position from its current position, and divides by time. Pretty simply stuff. Here is the complete working source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        * {
            background-color:#000000;
        }

        html {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        #readout {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            border: 8px solid #34a1ff;
            width: 162px;
            height: 100px;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .text {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="readout">
            <span id="xLabel" class="text">X: </span>
            <span id="xValue" class="text"></span>
            <br>
            <span id="yLabel" class="text">Y: </span>
            <span id="yValue" class="text"></span>
        </div>
        <script>
        // Where the speed will be displayed
        window.xDisplay = document.getElementById("xValue");
        window.yDisplay = document.getElementById("yValue");

        // Keep track of last time mouse was moved
        window.lastTime = new Date().getTime();
        window.lastDeltaTime = 0;
        window.lastMouseX = 0;
        window.lastMouseY = 0;
        window.lastVX = 0; // for smoothing
        window.lastVY = 0;

        // Listen for mouse move event
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 

            // Get current mouse position
            var currentX = e.clientX || e.pageX;
            var currentY = e.clientY || e.pageY;

            // Get distance travelled from last mouse position
            var deltaX = currentX - lastMouseX;
            var deltaY = currentY - lastMouseY;

            // Update mouse position
            lastMouseX = currentX;
            lastMouseY = currentY;

            // Get current time
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

            // Get time elapsed since last mouse event
            var deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;

            // Update last time
            lastTime = currentTime;

            // Get velocity components
            var xSpeed = deltaX / deltaTime;
            var ySpeed = deltaY / deltaTime;

            // Smooth out velocity
            var xSmooth = (xSpeed*2 + lastVX)/3;
            var ySmooth = (ySpeed*2 + lastVY)/3;

            // Update previous components
            lastVX = xSpeed;
            lastVY = ySpeed;

            // Display velocity
            xDisplay.innerHTML = xSmooth.toFixed(3);
            yDisplay.innerHTML = ySmooth.toFixed(3);

        }, false);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will be used in an app that is intended to run in fullscreen mode. The problem I encounter is when the cursor ends up all the way at an edge of the screen, and the user keeps moving the mouse in that direction. (Example: the cursor is all the way at the right edge of the screen, but the user keeps moving their mouse toward the right).

In the above scenario, the app displays a velocity of zero, since the cursor position is not being updated. However, I am in need to a solution that continues to display the actual mouse velocity even after the cursor has reached the edge (none of the similar questions on this site address this issue).

This is important since the use case will be in a WebGL context in which the mouse is used to control rotation from a first person view. The user needs to be able to keep on rotating their view around as many times as they want where rotation velocity is based on mouse velocity (not position!) and this simply doesn't work by calculating mouse speed from cursor position.

This may require some creativity but I'm sure it can be done. Thanks in advance for any solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, in case anyone ever stumbles upon this later.

The [Pointer Lock API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/) does exactly what I needed.